# Accessing multi-level JSON with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I have this JSON:

```
{
  "projects": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "children": [
        {
          "id": 2,
          "parent_id": 1,
          "project_name": "Carmichael Kitchen"
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "parent_id": 1,
          "project_name": "Carmichael Master Bedroom"
        },
        {
          "id": 4,
          "parent_id": 1,
          "project_name": "Carmichael Living Room"
        }
      ],
      "parent_id": 0,
      "project_name": "Carmichael"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to display its contents with jQuery:

```
ajaxRequest.done(function(data) { 
    var jdata = JSON.parse(data);
    $.each(jdata, function(){ 
        $('#mydivname').append(projects.project_name);
    }
});
```

However, I can't seem to access `project_name` as it is 'undefined.'

What am I missing here? I feel it is something really simple that I am overlooking. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You never defined a value for the `projects` variable.

Comment: Your each should be operating upon `jdata.projects`.

Comment: You can use a combination of [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [.flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to get project names and append it accordingly.

    ajaxRequest.done(function(data) { 
        var jdata = JSON.parse(data);
        const projects = jdata["projects"].map(x => x.children).flat().map(x => x.project_name);
     
     projects.forEach(x => {
      $('#mydivname').append(x);
     });
    });

Comment: @KunalMukherjee if you want to show some code, put it in a fiddle and link it in the comments.  It's very hard to read multi-line code in comments.